# Cannot create instance of ViewModel class error in code

Tags: android

I am experimenting with MVVM and following a tutorial. When I run my app the error occurs that "cannot create instance of view model" Since I am new to this I don't know why its giving error. Here is my code.

**Main Acitivity**

```
    UserViewModel userViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
    userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<User> users) {
            //update recyclerview here
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**View Model**

```
 public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private UserRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<User>> allUsers;

    public UserViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new UserRepository(application);
        allUsers = repository.getAllUsers();
    }
    public void insert(User user)
    {
        repository.insert(user);
    }
    public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers()
    {
        return allUsers;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
   public class UserRepository {
    private UserDao userDao;
    private LiveData<List<User>> allUsers;

    public UserRepository(Application application)
    {
        UserDatabase database = UserDatabase.getInstance(application);
        userDao = database.userDao();
        allUsers = userDao.getAllUsers();
    }

    public void insert(User user)
    {
        new Thread(new InsertInBackground(userDao,user)).start();
    }
    public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers()
    {
        return allUsers;
    }

    private static class InsertInBackground implements Runnable
    {
        private UserDao userDao;
        private User user;
        public InsertInBackground(UserDao userDao, User user)
        {
            this.userDao = userDao;
            this.user = user;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            userDao.insert(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Any help will be appreciated. Kindly don't duplicate this question because the related question answer is in kotlin and first i dont know kotlin second i dont understand whats happening there.

Comment: `Kindly don't duplicate this question` if it's a duplicate, then it's a duplicate, no matter how much you would like for it not to be :)

Comment: userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

Comment: @KishanMaurya in the tutorial the person uses "ViewModeProviders" but its depreciated now so i search and found out that i can use " userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class); " instead. but its also giving some error

Comment: remove new and try you are not supposed to instantiate ViewModelProvider class

Comment: @AgentP removing new also give error and its suggest to add new.

Comment: @a_local_nobody kindly understand that it may be a duplicate but it is not required that one question can only have one answer.

Comment: if the duplicate in question uses kotlin and your question uses java, then it's probably fine, but otherwise it's just a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Well i searched the comments of video and some nice soul posted this.

userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,                   ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(UserViewModel.class);

Well it makes my app work without crash but it looks like i have to do some more study on ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewMolde extends from `AndroidViewModel`, you should use AndroidViewModel when you need the AppContext in your Viewmodel, so the error is telling you that you need to pass de context. If you don't need the context, you have to extend from ViewModel.

To initialize ViewModel:

1. `ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class)`
2. `ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(ViewModel.class)`

To initialize AndroidViewModel you should create a Factory class to create your AndroidViewModel.